# JAVA - End a loop after 10 repeats

Tags: java

i'm writing a game where the user needs to guess a number between 0-100. the user has 10 tries to guess the right number and after every input he needs to get back a comment.
so i wrote the code and everything works pretty good but i have a problem with breaking the loops after 10 wrong guesses and starting the game again once the game ends.
anything would help. thank you in advace!

```
Scanner guess = new Scanner (System.in);
Random hundred = new Random ();
System.out.println ("Welcome to Magic Number!");
System.out.println ("I'm thinking about a number between 0-100. You have 10 rounds to guess the right number.");
System.out.println ("Good Luck!");
int number = hundred.nextInt(101);
while (true) {
    System.out.println ("What is the number i'm thinking about?");
    int guess1 = guess.nextInt();
     if (guess1 > number) {
        System.out.println ("The number you gueesed is higher than the number i'm thinking about!"); 
    } else if (guess1 < number) {
        System.out.println ("This number you guessed is lower than the number i'm thinking about!");
    } else if (guess1 == number) {
        System.out.println ("Congratulations! You've read my mind!");
        break;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` loops forever. Loop on a counter that you increment every time an incorrect guess is entered.

Comment: Just like you declared `number`, create a counter: `int tries = 1;`, then change the while to `while (tries <= 10)`.  Don't forget to increment your counter inside the while loop somewhere with `tries++;`.

Comment: For the second part, starting another game, you can put all of that game logic INSIDE another while loop so it can start again.  You'll have to put in logic that asks if they want to play again and breaks out if they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add  numberOfTimes  inside your while loop
look at the code below:

```
int numberOfTimes = 10;

while (numberOfTimes > 0) {
    System.out.println ("What is the number i'm thinking about?");
    int guess1 = guess.nextInt();
     if (guess1 > number) {
        System.out.println ("The number you gueesed is higher than the number i'm thinking about!"); 
    } else if (guess1 < number) {
        System.out.println ("This number you guessed is lower than the number i'm thinking about!");
    } else if (guess1 == number) {
        System.out.println ("Congratulations! You've read my mind!");
        break;
    }
    numberOfTimes--;
}
```